# Launch a separate process with a different root directory without forking/cloning it

Tags: c, linux-kernel, posix, systemd, posix-api

In my case, I need to launch a process on a daily basis from a separate filesystem with it’s root directory inside a subdirectory. As it is the only on the filesystem thing I need to umount it.
The other problem is I can’t`fork()`/`clone()`the process since it run inside a privileged ring.

I thought to the following solution:

```
char *argv [] = {"/path2/sbin/the_program_to_be_launched","-option","value of option",NULL};
char *envp [] = {"HOME=/","SHELL=no_shell_available","LC_ALL=C",NULL};
mount(name, "/path/", fs, flags, data);
chroot("/path/");
execve("/path2/sbin/the_program_to_be_launched",argv,envp); // would not work because the program won’t be able find his libraries
umount("/"); // would never be called if execve() would have been called correctly
```

And something like this without executing the process would not work too.

```
mount(name, "/path/", fs, flags, data);
chroot("/path/path2/"):
umount("/"); // would not work since "/" is not the root of the device.
```

So how to launch a different child with a different root directory and without changing the one of the parent process?

Comment: The argv and envp arrays need to be NULL terminated`char *argv [] = {"/path/path2/sbin/the_program_to_be_launched","-option","value of option", NULL};` so your execve() might fail (similar for envp[])

Comment: Just mount your volume, fork a child, let the child do the `execve()` call and let the parent wait for the child to terminate. After that, the parent can unmount the volume again.

Comment: @cmaster : In that case I won’t be able to umount the filesystem from which the child process was run, as shown is the second example.

Comment: this 'char argv [][]' should be either 'char * argv[]' or 'char ** argv'

Comment: @user2284570 Yes, you will be able to unmount, but you must use the parent process for unmounting that has never done a `chroot()` or `execve()`. Of course, you need to ensure that this parent does not unmount the filesystem before the child has finished its work, that's what the `wait()` call is for.

Comment: @cmaster : No I don't wait the end of the process for the`umount()`because I use the`MNT_DETACH`option.

Comment: @user2284570 Yes, that is another option you have. Keeping a parent process around to do the unmounting may have been a bit more portable, but on linux `MNT_DETACH` seems to be the path of least resistance :-)

Answer (score 0):

crom could launch the shell script that launches the actual program .

in Linux, the '/' directory is the root of ALL file systems. So you definitely do not want to be unmount'ing it. do read the man page on mount/unmount.

You could place an appropriate entry in the fstab for a user mountable filesystem. then mount'ing/unmount'ing it would be relatively simple.

you could create a ''restricted' user that the script logs on/logs off.

That user could be used to run the target program and perform the mount/unmount operations.

the shell run by crom could perform all the CD's, etc

to have the application program be able to execute without being able to see its' libraries, perhaps link it 'static'.  perhaps have the users' .profile include the development of the $PATH variable to include the path(s) to the libraries.

the logon of the user could use a version of busybox that only has the commands the user needs to run the target program.

Comment: You obviously don’t know what`chroot()`does. If you do`chroot("/path/");`and then`umount("/");`is the same thing as writing `umount("/path");`directly. It doesn’t target the real root. but the there is only one process is the chroot target which is run from a subdirectory of a filesystem mounted in a subdirectory of the real root. The point is to unmount the filesystem which was mounted in the single purpose.

Answer (score 0):

On a Unix-like system,the only way to create a new process is the system call `fork` or `clone`, and the `execv.` family the only way to launch an executable. There are indeed other fonctions like `system`, but they do call those two system calls.

Of course, on another system it can be different. On Windows for example, the API to start à new process is `CreateProcess`.

But on Unix or Linux, you will have to `clone` or `fork`. You can change the root file system with `chroot` and drop privilèges with `setuid` or its dérivations (provided calling process is privilèges).

Comment: In reality I am using the functions listed [here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/syscalls.h). The process run from the kernel but it does run in user-space mode.

Comment: Please say exactly what runs in kernel mode and what in user mode (and why...)

Comment: Every thing I am writing in the kernel is in user-mode. The point add some fs tasks to the ones performed by the mainline kernel before init is launch. The parts to which I am talking about are using the pid 1. The init process is finally launched by an execve().